# Using SWI-Prolog with Eclipse and Java (and JUNG): Should I use ProDT, PDT, or both?

Tags: java, eclipse, swi-prolog, jung, jpl

I want to use SWI-Prolog, Eclipse, and Java together and I have two interrelated related issues:

1. I don't know if I should use [ProDT](http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/), [PDT](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start) or both in combination.
2. PDT says that it includes a "subsystem that enables Java code to interact with SWI-Prolog". I don't know if this is sufficient on its own, or if I should use [InterProlog](http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/), [JPL](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/) or some combination of the three.

#### Background

I want to interact with an existing java code base which uses [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) for its datatypes, so a tidy fit to the java object heirarchy could be useful. (I want to apply constraints with JUNG objects such as trees and graphs as my domain--although I am willing to do this in a roundabout way if needed, i.e. by mapping the JUNG objects to data types more managable with SWI's available constraint modes.)

I want to deploy to PC and MAC, and also want to try out the [CHRrp package](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/CHR/CHRrp/) for SWI.

Answer (score 0):

```
I use jpl, it's quite easy to set up and use. But internet lot of trash tut so we may be confused. If you want that. here my note: 
Set enviroment variable: system variables ->add new ->JAVA_HOME (for jdk)
add new -> SWI_HOME_DIR (installation prolog folder path)
add this to Path: %SWI_HOME_DIR%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%;
add jpl.jar to referenced in project Java eclipse
```

Comment: Can we see your answer in **english**?